# BitBucket - configurate Wiki to viewable only

Tags: bitbucket

Is it possible to configurate a wicki on BitBucket so it is visible to everyone, but only editable by developers?

On BitBucket, I only see 3 options:
- No Wiki
- Private (hidden for everyone)
- Public (visible *and* editable for everyone)

In Public mode, anyone can make changes wich are immediatly visible by everyone - that can't be it, right?

I mean - the tutorial says "most developers use the wiki as their website".

Thanks!

Comment: Can't say for sure, but to me it doesn't look like that's possible

Comment: But - whats the idea behind such a concept? Communicate anarchic ideologies? ;)

Comment: it does seem a little odd. If indeed that is the case you could try and [create a feature request](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/new) and hope other people want that too.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no such feature jet.**
(Check out https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+a+wiki)
There already is a feature-request dough. Vote if you yearn for the feature too:

[Feature-Request](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/2462/allow-admins-to-specify-read-write-admin)